# Crashlytics - how can I delete builds/versions?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-beta

I want to delete 2 of the builds/versions from the Crashlytics dashboard — they were uploaded with the wrong version number and it's creating havoc in the testing process.

I would prefer to completely *and* totally remove them from Crashlytics.

Answer (score 60):

Alex from Fabric here. If you want to archive a version of your app, head to:

https://fabric.io/settings/apps

Then select your app, click on the Versions tab, and disable any versions you no longer need.

You can't technically delete an app, because maybe someone has downloaded it and you want to still receive its crash reports. Hence you can only restrict others from downloading it moving forward

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. If I follow these instructions I get "This will stop collecting any information about crashes for version xxx of yyy. It will also hide the version from being shown in the Crashlytics interface." I don't want to stop collecting information for that version number, because it is live. What do I do if I want to delete a beta build?

Comment: If you mean deleting it from the Beta dashboard, those versions are linked to the versions on the Crashlytics dashboard. A Beta build can't be hidden from Beta but continue to repot crashes through Crashlytics.

Comment: So the answer is actually "you can't"? Seems to be no good reason to disallow this. I have an app with version X on the AppStore, and a beta build with the wrong version number (also X). Why would I want to keep that beta build in the system? (I don't)

Comment: Similar issue here. I have several builds with the same version and one was broken from the start. I already revoked access for the testers but it's sitting in Beta and it's staring at me :)

Comment: I use Beta, with many builds for external testers... confirming I can remove unwanted builds by OFF "version-enabled", need to click on "( + )" next to version number. Thanks!

Comment: @Alexizamerican Question is related to removal of specific version of build, not of whole app. I have case where Fabric uploaded build without signing it, because xcode-select was not set, and I cannot remove this particular version form beta.

Comment: @Alexizamerican I am trying to delete a version from Firebase, can you please share the steps for it.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings -> APPS -> select your app -> Click on versions tab -> disable accident version.

Answer (score -2):

To delete a specific app version/build/flavor from Crashlytics/Fabric:

1. Go to https://fabric.io/settings/apps
2. Select the app version/build/flavor you want to delete
3. On the screen you will see the following options

Enable Privacy Prompt | 
Enable Answers Enhanced Feature Set |
Disable IP Address Tracking |
Delete App

To delete, select the last option.  Please note you must be an admin

Comment: He doesn't want to delete the whole app, just a specific build.