# All crashes with insights no longer show details?

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I have a number of crashes in the dashboard that are denoted as having insights.  Great!

Unfortunately every single one of those crashes shows "Hmm, we could not fetch session information" when I click for Issue Details.  Showing neither insights nor any other useful information.

Is there a workaround?  Or is this a bad Crashlytics dashboard update?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. That sounds like a bug on our end. I'd recommend emailing support(at)fabric(dot)io with a reference to this post and a link to your dashboard.

Comment: I am seeing this same issue as of today Mar 29, 2018.

Comment: At some point this resolved itself, so this must have been a temporary server issue of some variety.

Comment: I am seeing it too

Answer (score 0):

Please check that your Fabric admin did not [delete or disable a build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042432/crashlytics-how-can-i-delete-builds-versions). Doing so can cause this symptom.