# Firebase Crashlytics - disable version

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

I've migrated our apps from [Fabric](https://fabric.io)'s Crashlytics to [Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com/) Crashlytics, since Fabric's dashboard will be [shut down](https://get.fabric.io/roadmap) on March 31, 2020.

In Fabric's dashboard, I could disable a particular version (so its crashes won't show in unfiltered crash list) as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32075915/1233652).

I couldn't find similar functionality in **Firebase** dashboard. Is there a way to disable a particular version there?

Comment: I've also checked the [guide](https://docs.fabric.io/android/examples/firebase/index.html) which was created for smooth Crashlytics transition from Fabric to Firebase, but it doesn't mention version disabling.

Comment: I am using firebase crashlytics recently, I did not see the option to disable version. but you can filter the versions.

Comment: @majuran I'm aware to the fact that I can filter versions, though I'm specifically interested in viewing unfiltered (or in more common case: group-filtered using asterisk) results. In such scenario, there are specific versions which are irrelevant and I want to delete their data.

Comment: I suggest contacting [Fabric support](https://support.crashlytics.com/) or [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) if you're having problems with the console.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks! I've contacted Firebase support and received a very prompt response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've contacted Firebase's support and received response saying that there is currently no way to disable a particular version in same manner as it was possible in Fabric's dashboard, though they will consider to add similar functionality in future releases.