# How can I delete/unwatch version in crashlytics?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm trying to delete version from my crashlytics tab as they are not necessary.

I've already seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042432/crashlytics-how-can-i-delete-builds-versions) which exactly what I need but for Firebase, this new app isn't on Fabrics as they'll migrate to Firebase in a month or so.

I haven't been able to find the same functionality as in Fabrics. If anyone knows that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, after reaching to Firebase support, I got this answer:

> We have received similar requests to add support for enabling and disabling the monitoring of a specific version of your app. I've raised your request to our engineering team, and this will be evaluated for consideration. However, I cannot guarantee when this feature will be officially rolled out.
>
> For now, you may keep an eye out on our [Firebase blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/) or [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases) for any latest news or new features that we may have. We appreciate that you have expressed your feedback as this makes Firebase a better place for everyone.